# Vista freezes on black screen before login

Tags: windows-vista, freeze

My computer was running fine the last time i used it last week, but the next time i used it, it got stuck on a black screen with the cursor in the middle, and i couldn't move the cursor. When i tried entering again, i went to boot it on safe mode and had the same problem, then i tried system restore and last known configuration to no success.

I gave my computer to my dad, since he knows more than me, and he couldn't fix it, so he installed windows 7, now it has windows vista and 7 installed, but i can only use it when i load up 7, if i try loading vista i still get the same problem, and i can't access any of the files i had on vista (schoolwork, music, ect.) from 7, and i really need some of those files.

Does anyone know how i can fix this? or how can i access the files?